# Where is .block file stored/persisted?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When command "**peer channel fetch 0 mychannel.block -c mychannel --orderer orderer0.****.com:7050**" is executed in a peer's cli container, does it mean fetching mychannel.block from the **orderer**(orderer0.****.com:7050)? If so, does it mean that mychannel.block is stored in orderer instead of peer? And **where** is mychannel.block stored and persisted, is it stored by orderer container?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Orderer never reads, processes or stores the data. Orderer within the fabric network is responsible for:

- Creating the blocks in the correct sequence after the receiving transaction proposal requests from the application.
- Delivering these blocks to the anchor peers that have subscribed to the Orderer.

Now, coming to the command:

```
peer channel fetch 0 mychannel.block -c mychannel --orderer orderer0.****.com:7050
```

Here, we're passing two important information:

- Channel ID, using -c
- Ordering Service Endpoint, --orderer

Here, you pass the ordering service endpoint because the ordering service provides an interface to the peer for interacting with the channel. This is because a peer can be connected to multiple channels and these channels might've different orderers.

Next, to the following query:

> where is mychannel.block stored and persisted, is it stored by orderer container?

It is quite clear that Orderer container does not store any data. This data is stored within the peer's channel(ledger) itself. Ordering service just acts as an interface to connect to the channel and deliver mychannel.block.

Comment: Thanks so much. You mentioned "Ordering service just acts as an interface to connect to the channel and deliver mychannel.block.". So does it mean that mychannel.block is stored in peers? If I executed the fetch command from peer0.org1, it will fetch mychannel.block from other peers, right?

Comment: It will fetch from the ledger of the peer from which you’re issuing this command.

Comment: I don't think so. I have done an experiment. After I removed all the peers' containers, I re-launch all peers' containers. At that time, there is no data in the every peer's container. After that, .block file can be gotten by fetch command from orderer. In addition, in the orderer container's directory /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains/mychannel/, just now I found out that a file named "blockfile_000000", I think this should be the .block file.That is to say, the orderer actually stores .block file. This is my understanding.

Comment: Removed the peer containers? Does that mean you stopped the container or you pruned and removed the container along with its data? And did you do it for all the peers of all the organisations?

Comment: Yes, exactly, rm all orgs' peers containers, but keep orderers,kafka and zookeepers there.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @LinCorey. If you enter the docker container of the orderer and go to /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains, you'll see a folder for each channel, and inside of them, all the blockfiles.